# Не появляется Scrollbar у виджета Label Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

```
def show_list():
    global anime_list, text
    anime_list = Label(window, text=Anibot_lists.list, font=("Times Roman", 12), justify=LEFT, borderwidth = 5,
         relief="sunken",)
    anime_list.place(relx=.3, rely=place_list)
    text = Text(anime_list)
    text.place(relx=.3, rely=place_list)
    scroll = Scrollbar(anime_list, command=text.yview)
    text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll.place(relx=1) #Я не знаю правильно я расположил или нет, но мне нужно чтобы скроллбар просто находился справа от anime_list
    text.insert(END, anime_list))
```

Я смотрел один ролик(вот ссылка на него https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsm1nLevj0) про то как привязать скроллбар к лейбл объекту, вроде сделал всё как у него но скроллбар не появился просто.
Я пробовал вместо place использовать grid как у него, и хоть криво, но скролл появился.
И так: **Как я могу реализовать скролл, но используя place?**

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: А в чём смысл запихивания `Label` в `Text`? Если можно просто вывести нужный текст в сам `Text`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981244/4804629

Comment: @GrAnd я так понимаю, наоборот - текст запихивается в label

Comment: Тоже бред.  Да, в видео по ссылке текст запихивается напрямую в `Text`. А `Label` там вообще незнамо как используется, аля контейнер для `Text`. Так вообще никто не делает, да и незачем.

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, я попробую воспользоваться этим способом, а потом отпишу сюда если получится.